# Relation between canvas coordinates and screen coordinates android

Tags: android, android-canvas

What is the relation between screen's X and Y and canvas's X and Y. Suppose canvas's height is half of screen's height and it's center aligned. Now, i want to draw something with respect to screen's coordinates. What should I do? Please help

Comment: `View#getLocationOnScreen`

Answer (score 0):

When you draw in your canva in your onDraw method it is relative to your view. You can't draw beyond your view. For exemple if your view is at the position x = 0, y = 0, width = 50, height = 50. If you try to draw a line in your view like that canva.drawline(25,0,100,0) it's just gonna draw a line from 25x to 50x in your view, it's not gonna go beyond the limit of the View.

Tell me if you need clarification ;).

Edit:
So taking your exemple:
If your view is at the position 200dp, 100dp, 50w, 50h. Let's say you want to draw a line from the 0x,0y axes of your screen to the edge 0x,0y axes of your view. For this you have to do a custom that will match_parent in width and height. Then you will have to have the x, y of your view (view.getX(), view.getY()). The in the onDraw you'll just have to do that:

```
canvas.drawLine(0,0, myview.getX(), myview.getY(), paint);
```

You can have something like that:

[image: drawline]

Comment: I got your point. But my question is, how to convert onscreen coordinates to canvas coordinates? Suppose I have an images's onscreen X and Y and want to draw a line trailing this image.

Comment: My view is match_parent so I can't go further lol. you can still remove the actionBar or let the actionBar and calculate the height of it and make: canvas.drawLine(0,0-actionbarHeight, myview.getX(), myview.getY(), paint);

Comment: OP needs View<->"physical screen" relation, that is how to  map point [0,0] of the View to the screen